# Notation to select column from matrix

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors

Consider a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}_{n \times m}$.

One compact yet unclear notation to select a row or column from this matrix is:

$$x \in X$$

How do you clearly select a row or column from a matrix?

I know $X = (x_{ij})$ is a standard notation to select elements. Though I haven't seen this used, $x_i \in X_{ij}$ for rows and $x_j \in X_{ij}$ for columns might make sense. This is motivated by a similar notation I have seen, namely $\sum\limits_{i}X_{ij}$ for row sum or $\sum\limits_{j}X_{ij}$ for column sum.

Comment: My apologies if this is answered. Search engines find the question very ambiguous without context.

Comment: You can take the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$ to be $e_1,\dots,e_n$, then the $i$'th column is just $Xe_i$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could for example use [elementary vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis). Let $e_j$ be an $m \times 1$ vector of zeros with a one in $j$-th position. Then

$$
x_j = X e_j
$$

would be the $j$-th column of $X$.